# Этот день был долгим, но погода была хорошая!

Tags: падежи, творительный-падеж

В конструкции `этот день был долгим`, прилагательное имя находится в творительном падеже, но вот здесь `это был долгий день` - в именительном падеже.
Пожалуйста, скажите, всегда ли это правда `существительное + был + прилагательное в ТП` и `был + существительное и прилагательное в ИП`?
В учебнике я увидел следующее предложение `Погода была хорошая, и у нас было хорошее настроение`, почему они не написали так `Погода была хорошей, и у нас настроение было хорошим`?

So, yes I was searching for the most proper translation of the English one 'it was a long day' in Russian, so could you please tell me that one too.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что оно не должно находиться в творительном падеже? Раскройте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос, в нынешнем виде я вынужден его закрыть. Потому что вопрос "почему тут такой падеж" вообще говоря, имеет довольно неконструктивный ответ - потому.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the OP means the expression "I've had a long day" (and its variants) which he literally translates into Russian. A warning, then - Russians don't use a phrase "мой день был долгим" in the English sense of it.

Comment: You can also use nominative case (именительный падеж) and say 'день был долгий', and this will be grammatically correct :-) but it is used more rarely. Please expand your question, if you want to know the difference.

Comment: In _это был долгий день_, _долгий_ is in Nominative because it is an attribute to _день_ which is Nominative, and attributes agree with the noun they refer to.

Comment: If English is your native than you'd know better than me that ["It's been a long day"](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-phrase-its-been-a-long-day-mean) and its variants have a specific connotation. The equivalent phrase in Russian does not have this connotation. That's what my comment was about.

Comment: @tum_ I agree with you, in English this phrase "it's been a long day" is really an idiomatic expression, BUT in Russian we also have this connotation so that "долгий день" or "длинный день" means you are tired in the end of it. Here is an [example](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zFMH5ARYsUYC&pg=PA88&dq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB-o-FoKzmAhXIdN8KHbTICfAQ6AEIXjAG#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%22&f=false).

Comment: @farfareast :) Well, there is quite a difference between `Это был длинный день` and `... и, как только коснулась головой подушки, провалилась в сон с мыслью: "Господи, какой же это был длинный день!"` I wouldn't argue that one can express their fatigue in Russian using some phrase built on "длинный день", I simply warned a foreigner not to assume that idiomatic phrases preserve their meanings in their literal translations...

Answer (score 1):

*It was a long day* I would translate as *это был долгий день*. *Этот день был долгим* is also grammatically correct but it would be a translation of English *that day was long*.

As for your hypothesis:

```
существительное + был + прилагательное в ТП (_День был жарким._)
был + существительное и прилагательное в ИП (_Был жаркий день._)
```

It is not exactly right.

The first part can be used with both ТП and ИП. *День был жаркий* or *День был жарким*.

The second part, if it is the full sentence (*Был солнечный день.*), requires Nominative. If you have more words before, for example, you have *Он* in front of *был*, then again both cases are possible: *Он был умным человеком*, and *Он был умный человек*.

As for the difference between ИП and ТП after *был*, more often we use ТП. For example, *книга была интересной*. *Книга была интересная* sounds a bit archaic to me, but is still used.

Why we prefer using Instrumental case? Probably because we mentally substitute *был* to *являлся* (let's translate it to English as '*played a role of*' to also require an indirect object). *Являться* (кем, чем) requires Instrumental case (I hope you will not ask why :-). So, one meaning of *быть* - is *являться*, the second meaning is just '*to be*, or *to exist*'. Normally, Russians tend to omit '*быть*' in this meaning, especially in present tense. *Он есть красивый* we say as just *Он красивый*. In the Past tense we cannot omit *был*, otherwise there would be no indication of the Past. But we still internally resist using *быть* in its '*to exist*' meaning (*Книга существовала интересная*) and prefer *Книга являлась интересной.* That's why we prefer the Instrumental case here. But this is just my hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Инструменталисом в данном случае управляет указательное местоимение 'этот'. Недопусимо 'этот день был долгий', но можно и 'день был долгим' (в таком случае имеем эллипсис, местоимение только подразумевается), и 'день был долгий' (какой-то неизвестный день). Прилагательные при дне и погоде лучше ставить в одном падеже.